# iphone memory allocations and leaks

Tags: iphone

How to solve memory allocation in ios ?give me the right way to solve memory issues and memory leaks.

Comment: First you have to accept some answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to avoid these Memory issues is through proper coding. Just go through the Apple reference on [Memory Management](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH).

> You only release or autorelease
>   objects you own.
>
> You take ownership of an object if you
>   create it using a method whose name
>   begins with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or
>   “mutableCopy” (for example, alloc,
>   newObject, or mutableCopy), or if you
>   send it a retain message.
>
> You use release or autorelease to
>   relinquish ownership of an object.
>   autorelease just means “send a release
>   message in the future” (specifically:
>   when the used autorelease pool
>   receives a drain message—to understand
>   when this will be, see “Autorelease
>   Pools”).

Answer (score 2):

Without more info all I can say is...

- Release anything you init and/or alloc that is not autoreleased.
- Delete anything that you call "new" on
- free any data you malloc
- Use Instruments to diagnose where your leaks are occuring.
- Release anything you retain

release anything you init that is not autoreleased.

Comment: Release anything you **retain** also.

Answer (score 1):

@Nipin, For solving memory issues, you'll have to release each object that you're allocating... ie, use `[yourObject release];` for each object you call `alloc` method... Also, unload any textures that you're using `[texturename unload];`

```
[texturename release];
```

Do all these when you no longer requires those objects or textures and in most cases it can be where you exit from the scene...

Answer (score 0):

follow the below link [memory management](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html)

another link is small guide for quick point [small article](http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/)